# Creating new groups, when the original groups do not have sufficient observations

Tags: r, data.table, cluster-analysis

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
sample <- fread("
1,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,0,cat X, type 4
1,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
3,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,35,cat Y, type 4
1,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,NA,cat X, type 4
1,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
3,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,1,cat Y, type 4
1,0,2,4,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat X, type 4
1,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
3,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat Y, type 4
")

names(sample) <- c("A","B","C", "D", "cat", "type")

sample <- sample[, observations := sum(!is.na(D)), by = c("cat", "type")]

    A B C  D   cat   type observations
 1: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1
 2: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3
 3: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3
 4: 3 4 3  0 cat X type 4            2
 5: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0
 6: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0
 7: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3
 8: 3 4 3 35 cat Y type 4            3
 9: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1
10: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3
...
24: 3 4 3  0 cat Y type 4            3
```

I would like to add the neighbouring group `type`s together if they have fewer than two observations.

For example: add the group of `type 1` with only 1 observation to the observations in group 2 (see the first line of the desired output).

Types need to be pooled together until all remaining categories have at least 2 observations. So `type 1` and `type 2` of `category Y`, need to be pooled with `type 3`.

I am having trouble coming up with way of writing code for this.

Can anyone suggest a good way to automatically create the new types?

I realise that there might be situations in which there might be two possible solutions for pooling the groups. However, as long as the groups which are added together are neighbouring groups (so `type 1` is not added to `type 4`, which groups are added together are not important.

Desired output:

```
    A B C  D   cat   type  new_type observations
 1: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1  type 2          4
 2: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2  type 2          4
 3: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3  type 3          3
 4: 3 4 3  0 cat X type 4  type 4          2
 5: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 1  type 3          3
 6: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2  type 3          3
 7: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3  type 3          3
 8: 3 4 3  0 cat Y type 4  type 4          3
 9: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1  type 2          4
10: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2  type 2          4
...
24: 3 4 3  0 cat Y type 4  type 4          3
```

**Solution does NOT have to use data.table**

Comment: Why are rows 3-4 singletons in your desired output? You said that if they have fewer than two, they should be combined with a neighboring group.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, mistake on my side, they are combined now.

Comment: @Waldi Fixed. My apologies, I keep overlooking the mistakes. I think I copied in a wrong table at some point, because of which I confused numbers. I went through the whole table again and I think it is correct now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Reduce` and `accumulate = T` option:

```
sample[,`:=`(type = last(type),observations=sum(observations)),
       .(cat,sapply(Reduce(f = function(x,y) {
                          grp= x$grp
                          if (x$nxtgrp) {grp=grp+1; x$cumsum=0}
                          nxtgrp=!((x$cumsum+y)<2)
                          list(grp = grp,
                               cumsum=x$cumsum + y,
                               nxtgrp = nxtgrp)},
                     x = observations,
                     init = list(grp = 0, cumsum=0, nxtgrp = F),
                     accumulate = T),
         function(x) x$grp)[-1])
       ][]

        A     B     C     D    cat   type observations
    <int> <int> <int> <int> <char> <char>        <int>
 1:     1     0     2    NA  cat X type 2            4
 2:     3     4     3     1  cat X type 2            4
 3:     1     0     2     2  cat X type 3            3
 4:     3     4     3     0  cat X type 4            2
 5:     1     0     2    NA  cat Y type 3            3
 6:     3     4     3    NA  cat Y type 3            3
 7:     1     0     2     2  cat Y type 3            3
 8:     3     4     3    35  cat Y type 4            3
 9:     1     0     2    NA  cat X type 2            4
10:     3     4     3     1  cat X type 2            4
11:     1     0     2     2  cat X type 3            3
12:     3     4     3    NA  cat X type 4            2
13:     1     0     2    NA  cat Y type 3            3
14:     3     4     3    NA  cat Y type 3            3
15:     1     0     2     2  cat Y type 3            3
16:     3     4     3     1  cat Y type 4            3
17:     1     0     2     4  cat X type 2            4
18:     3     4     3     1  cat X type 2            4
19:     1     0     2     2  cat X type 3            3
20:     3     4     3     2  cat X type 4            2
21:     1     0     2    NA  cat Y type 3            3
22:     3     4     3    NA  cat Y type 3            3
23:     1     0     2     2  cat Y type 3            3
24:     3     4     3     2  cat Y type 4            3
        A     B     C     D    cat   type observations
```

The idea is to generate an accumulated list with :

- the current group : `grp`
- the current cumsum : `cumsum`
- a flag to increment group for next row : `nxtgrp`

As soon as the number of observations is above 2, the flag to increment group is set.
When the flag is set, at next row, `cumsum` is reset to zero and `grp` is incremented.

The `grp` list element can then be used as `by` parameter in `data.table`.

Another possibility is to achieve the same grouping with a `for-loop` function either in R, or in Rcpp:

```
observations_grp <- function(x) {
  cumsum_i <- 0
  nxtgrp <-  F
  n <- length(x)
  grp <- rep(0,n)
  grp_i <- 0;
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (nxtgrp) {grp_i <- grp_i + 1; cumsum_i <- 0;}
    nxtgrp <- !((cumsum_i + x[i]) < 2)
    cumsum_i <- cumsum_i + x[i]
    grp[i] <- grp_i
  }
  grp
}

sample[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations=sum(observations)),
        .(cat,observations_grp(observations))
][]
```

A performance comparison shows that `Reduce` isn't faster than a R loop:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 Reduce 1.3458 1.45025 1.732185 1.56405 1.73740 6.3339   100
   Loop 1.3374 1.44175 1.685722 1.53120 1.67665 3.7091   100
```

If you need speed, Rcpp will definitely help a lot.

Comment: Hi Waldi, this is great, and I can reproduce your example, but I am having some trouble  seeing where `cat X/Y` comes in. When I run this on my actual data (it's more than fast enough by the way, so Rcpp won't be necessary), I see that `type 1` is sometimes changed to `type 4`, which is theoretically possible when there are less than two observation by `cat` in total, however according to my data, that should not be the case. Did I create an example which accidentally does not need `cat`?

Comment: *`type 4 to type 1`

Comment: I oversaw cat, and the example doesn't make a difference on cat : corrected

Comment: I had some issues applying the solution to my actual data. I managed to recreate the issue and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093679/making-a-function-that-automatically-creates-new-groups-independent-of-order

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can create a `helper` function like below

```
helper <- function(v) {
  s <- grp <- 0
  y <- vector("numeric", length(v))
  for (i in seq_along(v)) {
    y[i] <- grp
    s <- s + v[i]
    if (s >= 2) {
      s <- 0
      grp <- grp + 1
    }
  }
  y
}
```

then run

```
dt <- sample[
  ,
  c(.(grp = helper(observations)), .SD),
  .(id = rleid(cat))
][
  ,
  `:=`(type = last(type), observations = sum(observations)),
  .(id, grp)
][, -(1:2)]
```

and you will obtain

```
> dt
    A B C  D   type observations
 1: 1 0 2 NA type 2            4
 2: 3 4 3  1 type 2            4
 3: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
 4: 3 4 3  0 type 4            2
 5: 1 0 2 NA type 3            3
 6: 3 4 3 NA type 3            3
 7: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
 8: 3 4 3 35 type 4            3
 9: 1 0 2 NA type 2            4
10: 3 4 3  1 type 2            4
11: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
12: 3 4 3 NA type 4            2
13: 1 0 2 NA type 3            3
14: 3 4 3 NA type 3            3
15: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
16: 3 4 3  1 type 4            3
17: 1 0 2  4 type 2            4
18: 3 4 3  1 type 2            4
19: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
20: 3 4 3  2 type 4            2
21: 1 0 2 NA type 3            3
22: 3 4 3 NA type 3            3
23: 1 0 2  2 type 3            3
24: 3 4 3  2 type 4            3
    A B C  D   type observations
```

Comment: appending to `idx <- c(idx, ....)` is inefficient. declare it `idx <- vector(, length(v))` and fill it in a loop.

Comment: @jangorecki Thanks! Good point to speed up. Updated my solution already!

Comment: If it's integer then you are losing some time, by using double, rather than integer, in your helper function: +1 vs +1L.

Comment: @jangorecki Sounds interesting! Didn't know the difference between `integer` and `numeric` on speed before, but learn it now.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I had some issues applying your solution to my actual data. I managed to recreate the issue and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093679/making-a-function-that-automatically-creates-new-groups-independent-of-order I made the example with Waldi's answer, but I had the same results with your function. If you have any ideas I would be really happy to hear them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidyverse solution. The highest type level (type 4) will decrease when observations<2, other type will go one higher.

```r
library(dplyr)
sample %>% 
  mutate(
    new_type = as.numeric(factor(type)),
    new_type = paste0(
      "type ", 
      ifelse(observations<2,
             ifelse(new_type != max(new_type), new_type + 1, new_type - 1), 
             new_type)
      )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(cat, new_type) %>% 
  mutate(observations = sum(!is.na(D))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: That doesn't meet the desired output as this won't move more than one type above/below- see row #5 for example.