# Making a function that automatically creates new groups independent of order

Tags: r, data.table

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894399/creating-new-groups-when-the-original-groups-do-not-have-sufficient-observation) before. I can however not get it to work when the data gets slightly more complicated. Below (data at the bottom) I therefore created a slightly more complicated example. I added four complications.

- In `sample_dat`, there is simply an extra category for the `by` group.
- In `sample_dat2`, the rows are in random order.
- In `sample_dat3`, random rows are deleted.
- In `sample_dat4`, random rows are duplicated.

The data below shows the effect of these data imperfections on the answers of the question I linked to. It seems that the only problem is the order that I presented the data in (there seems to be no issue for additionally removing random rows). When duplicating random rows the same issue as in `sample_dat2` presents itself.

As a result it seems that the problem could be solved by getting reordering `sample_dat2`, so that it becomes `sample_dat`. The problem is that `sample_dat2_to1 <- sample_dat2[order(cat, year, type),]` does not result in `sample_dat`.

```
    A B C  D   cat   type observations year
 1: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2010
 2: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2010
 3: 1 0 2  4 cat X type 1            1 2010
 4: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
 5: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
 6: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
 7: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2010
 8: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2010
```

## Question

How do I either order my data to fit the function (revert `sample_dat2` back to `sample_dat`), or adapt the functions created by Waldi and ThomasIsCoding, to be independent of order.

## Data

```
sample_dat <- structure(list(A = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3), B = c(0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 
4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 
0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 
4), C = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3), D = c(NA, 1, 2, 0, NA, NA, 2, 
35, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, 
1, 2, 0, NA, NA, 2, 35, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
2, NA, NA, 2, 2), cat = c("cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat X", 
"cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat X", "cat X", "cat X", 
"cat X", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat X", "cat X", 
"cat X", "cat X", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat X", 
"cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", 
"cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat Y", "cat Y", "cat Y", 
"cat Y", "cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat X", "cat Y", "cat Y", 
"cat Y", "cat Y"), type = c("type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", 
"type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", 
"type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", 
"type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", 
"type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", 
"type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", 
"type 4", "type 1", "type 2", "type 3", "type 4", "type 1", "type 2", 
"type 3", "type 4"), observations = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 
0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3), year = c(2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))

sample_dat <- data.table(sample_dat)
set.seed(1)
sample_dat2 <- sample_dat[sample(nrow(sample_dat)),]
# row_nums <- floor(runif(10, min=1, max=48))
row_nums <- c(43, 14, 22, 16, 31, 13, 23, 37, 4, 42)
sample_dat3 <- sample_dat[-row_nums]
sample_dat4 <- rbind(sample_dat, sample_dat[row_nums])

observations_grp <- function(x) {
  cumsum_i <- 0
  nxtgrp <-  F
  n <- length(x)
  grp <- rep(0,n)
  grp_i <- 0;
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (nxtgrp) {grp_i <- grp_i + 1; cumsum_i <- 0;}
    nxtgrp <- !((cumsum_i + x[i]) < 2)
    cumsum_i <- cumsum_i + x[i]
    grp[i] <- grp_i
  }
  grp
}

sample_dat[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations=sum(observations)),
        .(cat, year ,observations_grp(observations))
][]

sample_dat2[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations=sum(observations)),
        .(cat, year ,observations_grp(observations))
][]

sample_dat3[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations=sum(observations)),
        .(cat, year ,observations_grp(observations))
][]


sample_dat4[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations=sum(observations)),
        .(cat, year ,observations_grp(observations))
][]
```

Comment: In the original linked question, the row order is integral to the outcome. New types are defined by the types of neighbouring rows. This data order needs some kind of index...otherwise it's like having time-series data without any time data to put points in the correct order after random shuffling? I don't see how it would be possible to revert `sample_dat2` to `sample_dat` without this?

Comment: @Roasty247 Thank you for your comment. I understand your point, but it seems that the sample I created (`sample_dat`) does have some kind of structure. What if `sample_dat2` was first ordered with `sample_dat2_to1 <- sample_dat2[order(cat, year, type),]` and subsequently every duplicate combination of the groups is moved to the bottom, until `sample_dat` is achieved (I although I have to admit that I am unsure how one would achieve this).

Comment: What is the structure of `sample_dat`? Unless for example, `sample_dat_to1 <- sample_dat[order(cat, year, type),]` is the same as `sample_dat` and predictable (which I can't find that it is, even with other orders of `cat`, `year` and `type`), then `sample_dat` isn't structured as you expect and trying to order `sample_dat2` according to this structure is not going to work? To me it looks like there is another variable missing to distinguish cases were `year`, `cat` and `type` are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the link between this question and your previous one with grouping, but I guess you could try `rowid` to order `sample_dat2` like below

```
> sample_dat2[order(year, rowid(year, cat, type), cat, type)]
    A B C  D   cat   type observations year
 1: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2010
 2: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
 3: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2010
 4: 3 4 3  0 cat X type 4            2 2010
 5: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2010
 6: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2010
 7: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2010
 8: 3 4 3  2 cat Y type 4            3 2010
 9: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2010
10: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
11: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2010
12: 3 4 3 NA cat X type 4            2 2010
13: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2010
14: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2010
15: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2010
16: 3 4 3  1 cat Y type 4            3 2010
17: 1 0 2  4 cat X type 1            1 2010
18: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2010
19: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2010
20: 3 4 3  2 cat X type 4            2 2010
21: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2010
22: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2010
23: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2010
24: 3 4 3 35 cat Y type 4            3 2010
25: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2020
26: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2020
27: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2020
28: 3 4 3  0 cat X type 4            2 2020
29: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2020
30: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2020
31: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2020
32: 3 4 3 35 cat Y type 4            3 2020
33: 1 0 2 NA cat X type 1            1 2020
34: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2020
35: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2020
36: 3 4 3  2 cat X type 4            2 2020
37: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2020
38: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2020
39: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2020
40: 3 4 3  2 cat Y type 4            3 2020
41: 1 0 2  4 cat X type 1            1 2020
42: 3 4 3  1 cat X type 2            3 2020
43: 1 0 2  2 cat X type 3            3 2020
44: 3 4 3 NA cat X type 4            2 2020
45: 1 0 2 NA cat Y type 1            0 2020
46: 3 4 3 NA cat Y type 2            0 2020
47: 1 0 2  2 cat Y type 3            3 2020
48: 3 4 3  1 cat Y type 4            3 2020
    A B C  D   cat   type observations year
```

which should give the same result as `sample_dat`

Comment: Thank you for you answer Thomas. The link with the previous question is (or at least I think it is) that my actual data is not in a nice order, while apparently the answer of the previous question required this "nice" order. By reordering my actual data in the same way as the sample in the previous question, the solution should work again (at least that is my thinking process). I will try it now.

Comment: This solution doesn't work 100% and is not reproducible. The `rowid()` of `sample_dat2` is dependent on the original random shuffle, and although it acts as an additional variable to sort the cases where `year`, `cat` and `type` are the same, the rows distinguished by `rowid()` can be in any random order with this sorting method. e.g. look at at column `D` and identify the rows == 35, they appear in different places when the code is repeated, and doesn't always replicate `sample_dat`.