# Using a function on multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have example data as follows:

## Example data

```
library(data.table)
sample_dat <- fread("
NA,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,0,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,35,cat Y, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
NA,4,3,NA,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,1,cat Y, type 4
1,0,2,4,cat X, type 1
3,4,3,1,cat X, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat X, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat X, type 4
NA,0,2,NA,cat Y, type 1
NA,4,3,NA,cat Y, type 2
1,0,2,2,cat Y, type 3
3,4,3,2,cat Y, type 4
")

names(sample_dat) <- c("A","B","C", "D", "cat", "type")
```

## Solution for column D

```
sample_dat <- sample_dat[, observations_D := sum(!is.na(D)), by = c("cat", "type")]
```

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937596) how I could add groups together if they have less than two observations, which can be done as follows:

```
observations_grp <- function(x) {
  cumsum_i <- 0
  nxtgrp <-  F
  n <- length(x)
  grp <- rep(0,n)
  grp_i <- 0;
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (nxtgrp) {grp_i <- grp_i + 1; cumsum_i <- 0;}
    nxtgrp <- !((cumsum_i + x[i]) < 2)
    cumsum_i <- cumsum_i + x[i]
    grp[i] <- grp_i
  }
  grp
}

sample_dat[,`:=`(type = last(type), observations_D =sum(observations_D)),
        .(cat,observations_grp(observations_D))
][]
```

I would now like to apply this solution not only for `D`, but loop this solution over the other columns as well. I attempted the following:

## Count observations for each variable of interest

```
# Create a vector with the variables to create the observations by type
vars_of_interest <-  c("A","B","C","D")
observations_by_col <- paste0("observations_", vars_of_interest)
setDT(sample_dat)[, (observations_by_col) := lapply(vars_of_interest, function(x)   sum(!is.na(get(x)))),by = c("cat", "type")]

# Copy a seperate type for each column to be overwritten
new_type_by_col <- paste0("new_type_", vars_of_interest)
setDT(sample_dat)[, (new_type_by_col) := type]

     A B C  D   cat   type observations_D observations_A observations_B observations_C new_type_A new_type_B new_type_C new_type_D
 1: NA 0 2 NA cat X type 1              1              1              3              3     type 1     type 1     type 1     type 1
 2:  3 4 3  1 cat X type 2              3              3              3              3     type 2     type 2     type 2     type 2
 3:  1 0 2  2 cat X type 3              3              3              3              3     type 3     type 3     type 3     type 3
 4:  3 4 3  0 cat X type 4              2              2              3              3     type 4     type 4     type 4     type 4
```

Now I would like to apply solution that is applied to `D` above, to all `vars_of_interest`. I tried the following, but I get stuck.

## Attempt for all columns

```
for (i in seq_along(vars_of_interest)) {

    sample_dat[, `:=` ( get(new_type_by_col[i]) )= last( get(new_type_by_col[i]) ), get( observations_by_col[i] ) =sum( get(observations_by_col[i]) ),
        .(cat,observations_grp( get(observations_by_col[i]) ) )
]

}
```

I however get the error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in
 for (i in seq_along(vars_of_interest)) {

        sample_dat[,`:=`(get(new_type_by_col[i]))=
```

I do not really understand why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

Comment: @zx8754 It works for me.. Here is the link to the whole question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894399/creating-new-groups-when-the-original-groups-do-not-have-sufficient-observation/73937596#73937596

Comment: I think it is a typo, check your paranthesis. `()`

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for your comment. I found one missing parenthesis, but after correcting the error remained the same. I put tabs between all parenthesis to have a better look (it seems they are fine now), but there is still something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think at least one parenthesis is not needed -

```
for (i in seq_along(vars_of_interest)) {

sample_dat[, `:=` ( get(new_type_by_col[i]) *)*= last( get(new_type_by_col[i]) ), get( observations_by_col[i] ) =sum( get(observations_by_col[i]) ),
    .(cat,observations_grp( get(observations_by_col[i]) ) )]}
```

the one highlighted by **.

Comment: Regretfully did not change anything!